# Fastest way to search for a list of files in directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a list of file names, I want to create the full path for these files if they exist in a given directory or it's sub-directories. Right now I use this code

```
def construct_path(file_list, directory):
    file_path_list = []
    for name in file_list:
        for dir, subdir, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            if name in filenames:
                file_path_list.append(os.path.join(dir, name))

    return file_path_list
```

So here the directory is being crawled for each file in the list. Is there a faster/better way to do it?

Comment: Reversing the order of the loops would probably do it. And maybe removing found names from `file_list` might help. Early exit if you find them all, too.

Comment: Look into this stuff, it uses native calls https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the loop over the `file_list` and remove found files from this list, so you can return the results once you have found all your files:

```
def construct_path(file_list, directory):
    file_path_list = []
    for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            if name in file_list:
                file_path_list.append(os.path.join(dir, name))
                file_list.remove(name)
            if (len(file_list)==0): return file_path_list
    return file_path_list
```

Comment: This still crawls directory for each file

Comment: Yes, but it does it only once, and you should be able to return earlier if you have found all the files before crawling all files.

Comment: Although it may seem just a swap of two loops, `os.walk` requires disk I/O, while `for name in files` occurs in memory, which is much faster.  That's why there's a speed gain in doing `os.walk` only once.